# How do I activate [routerLinkActive] after successful login?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that encompasses multiple child components which you can navigate to via a menu. I want the buttons in that menu to be disabled when the user hasn't logged in yet.

The login component is a child component of the main app component so it uses an event emitter to tell the main app component whether the login was successful or not. However, when I run the app I get an error stating:

```
ERROR TypeError: data.split is not a function
```

Also its giving me a compiler error which goes like this:

```
ERROR in src/app/app/login/login.component.ts(14,3): error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
```

This is my main app (template + component)

```
<header class="page-header">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsEnabled" (change) = "makeActive($event)">
        <a [routerLink]="['/account/create']">Account aanmaken</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsEnabled" (change) = "makeActive($event)">
        <a [routerLink]="['/account/list']">Account overzicht</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsEnabled" (change) = "makeActive($event)">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/create']">Verlofuren aanvragen</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsEnabled" (change) = "makeActive($event)">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/list']">Verlofuren overzicht</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="routerLinkActiveIsEnabled" (change) = "makeActive($event)">
        <a [routerLink]="['/leave/pending']">Verlofaanvragen overzicht</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Berichten&hellip;</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

main app component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;
  routerLinkActiveIsEnabled: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.title = "Verlofurenregistratie";
  }

  makeActive(event){
    this.routerLinkActiveIsEnabled = event
  }
}
```

This is the login child component:

template

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"
           placeholder="naam@mail.nl"
           formControlName="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control"
           formControlName="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Inloggen</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

component:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {AccountService} from "../account/account.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  providers: [AccountService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  @Output onLoginSuccessful = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  title: string;
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  error = '';
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private accountService: AccountService,
              private router: Router) {
    this.title = "Inloggen";
    this.loginForm = fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const formModel = this.loginForm.value;
    this.accountService.authenticate(formModel.email, formModel.password).then(account =>
    {console.log(account.id + " " + account.password + " " + " " + account.username + " "  + account.person + " ")
        if (account !== undefined) {
      this.onLoginSuccessful.emit(true)
      localStorage.setItem("account", JSON.stringify(account))
        this.router.navigate(["account/update", account.id])
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? thank you

EDIT: i've resolved the compiler issue by giving output an alias.

Comment: route link can be defined like this :   <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>, why there is need of [] as thre is no binding

Comment: This line: `@Output onLoginSuccessful = new EventEmitter<boolean>();` needs to have parenthesis after the @Output. Like this: `@Output()  onLoginSuccessful = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

Answer (score 0):

You use the RouterLinkActive directive wrong. It sets a css class on the active route element. So you did not need a extra property on your component to track the active route. You have only prepare a style for the element.

See the documentation of [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive).